# How do I run separate tests?

Tags: java, maven

How do I run a separate folder with the tests in a particular module?

My modules:

```
    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>foo</module>
        <module>bar</module>
</modules>
```

Each module has a 2-3 test folder. I need to run tests folder "utils" in the module bar.

I did limit for the team "MVN test" :

```
<plugins>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/utils/**</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>

      <execution>
        <id>surefire-itest</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>none</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>**/utils/**</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
```

mvn test - runs all the tests except the "utils".
mvn integration-test - runs all the tests.

Now I need to start only "utils". How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option one is to use [various profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to run different surefire exections (and different includes and excludes) via `mvn test`.

Option two is to use the [failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) with `mvn verify`.  This makes it easy to run unit tests only, or unit tests and integration tests; running integration tests only is possible but awkward.

Don't use the surefire plugin with `mvn integration-test`.  It's usually best not to use `mvn integration-test` at all.  See the [introduction to the maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

Create another  for just the tests in utils and bind it to the phase you want to run them in.

You could possibly group your tests using [categories](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html) as well if you are using JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem:

mvn test - runs all the tests except the "utils"
mvn test -P utilsTest - Only run tests "utils"

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>utilsTest</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <exclude>none</exclude>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/utils/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/utils/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```